# Running thrift server as daemon

Tags: python, thrift

Right now I'm testing the waters with Apache Thrift, and I'm currently using a `TThreadedServer` written in Python, but when I run the server, it is not daemonized. Is there any way to make it run as a daemon, or is there another way to run thrift in a production environment?

Comment: For me, I use ``supervisord`` to run as daemon. You can write a bash script to do that. But I prefer not too. Been there, done that myself. Google supervisord it might be the easiest way to run a service. There is one thing though: supervisor does not kill children. You have to use groupkills to kill children.

Comment: Is running the daemon with `supervisord` robust enough for a production environment?

Comment: supervisord is just a small program that knows how to manage processes. It's definitely scalable. People run this on hundreds of vms. When you scale, you don't look at daemon. You have to have lots of instances. You need to load balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daemonizing processes has nothing to do with thrift. Thrift only provides the communication layer for different platforms and you can run the server in one of the several programming languages thrift supports (that is - great majority of what you can think of). No matter if you write the server in Java, C++ (I've tried those so far) or python, none of them will create a daemon. This feature is not supported (e.g. PHP natively doesn't support neither multithreading nor daemonizing).

I've just seen supervisord, didn't play with it much, but it seems to be a good choice to manage processes like thrift servers.

Comment: So how would you run thrift servers in production then?

Comment: One possibility is to run them from `supervisord`, less civilized way is to run them under a `screen`. I'm sure there are more solutions.

Comment: I have seen one very big calculation system (10+ developers working on it) that had both test and prod environment run on supervisord. It can scan memory usage, notify when anything goes down, etc. It's quite easily configurable. As far as I remember, you'd define one job in the config which would just run python thrift server and that's all (one line I guess)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:
nohup hbase thrift start &

This is the only way I found to keep thrift working after my disconnect from Linuxsession.